# Error installing SQL Server Express on Windows 10 Home 21H2, 19044.1526 - Unauthorized operation

Tags: installation, sql-server-express

I hit the same error again and again when trying to install SQL Server Express 2019 (or older versions on two different Windows 10 Home 21H2, 19044.1526 PC's.

I get this error:

```
Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84BB0001
  Error description:             Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%400xBB814387&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%400xBB814387*
```

Microsoft has an KB article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/install/error-set-up-update-instances about upgrading the Edge Chromium version. It is up to date, and I have tried installing Edge using a standalone installer also.
The registry subkey in mention: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Edge simply does not exist.

I try installing with a minimum of features. But the error appears with installing the  database engine, which is hard to live without.

Comment: Do you have anti-malware software installed? [BullGuard specifically is a known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/680707/getting-0x84bb0001-when-installing-sql-server-2019.html).

Comment: I think so yes. Would it be sufficient to deactivate that type of software or is it necessary to uninstall it?

Comment: I think it depends on the specific anti-malware product but I've head BullGuard must be uninstalled rather than just disabled.